# Rest-assured JsonPath working in JUnit Test but not when deployed in application (Weblogic)

Tags: junit, weblogic, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

A little background first.
I have an application that is deployed in Weblogic.  It receives a Json response from a Service.  I'm trying to use JsonPath to navigate the tree and I'm having an unusual issue.

I'm using Maven to build/deploy the application.
Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After getting it running with the full response in Junit and realizing that it wasn't working in the application when deployed, I made it simpler and hard coded a very small subset of the data.

```
{
    "ChangeStatus": {
        "Code": {
            "value": "1002"
        },
        "Description": {
            "value": "Matched more then 10 records"
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what I'm looking at right now...

```
String miniJson = "{\"ChangeStatus\":{\"Code\":{\"value\":\"1002\"},\"Description\":{\"value\":\"Matched more then 10 records\"}}}";
JsonPath miniJsonPath = new JsonPath(miniJson);
String statusCode = miniJsonPath.getString("ChangeStatus.Code.value");
```

In JUnit, this code works and I can assert 1002 successfully.
In the application after pushing to weblogic, this exact code snippet does not work.
It throws a NoSuchMethodError.

Any ideas would be welcome.
FYI, we are on Weblogic 10.3.6

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And you've verified your json-path-1.8.1.jar is part of your deployed app? What does the stack trace look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I discovered is that jsonpath depends upon antlr.
Weblogic also includes this package, but I believe it is an older version.

I fixed the problem by telling Weblogic to use the classes included in the app.
weblogic.xml

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Weblogic, but as an alternative you can include

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and create a class `ChangeStatus` with 2 members `Code` and `Description` and then you can deserialize the JSON using:

```
    `new ObjectMapper().readValue(miniJson, ChangeStatus.class)`
```

Hope it hepls.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I'm actually using that very code in other places in the application.  The piece I'm working with right now is far more complicated than what I displayed.  JsonPath is the most useful tool I've found to this point to handle the overly-nested nature of the Json I'm dealing with.  I did find the solution and will post it.